# Blowing up rational singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a normal variety over complex numbers, and having rational singularities. Consider an embedding $X\subset Y$, where $Y$ is smooth and $X$ is ample divisor on $Y$.
By Kollar's resolution of pairs, there is a pair $(X',Y')$ surjecting onto the pair $(X,Y)$: 
$f:(X',Y') \rightarrow (X,Y)$, such that $X', Y'$ are smooth.
$X'$ an ample divisor, does rational singularities imply that the fibres of $f$ are homogeneous spaces, example, product of projective spaces (since the fibres have vanishing $H^{i,0}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please don't post several questions as a single one. Besides, it will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: The fibers of $f$ can be reducible, for example if $X$ is a surface with a double rational point in $\Bbb C^3$.